# Как узнать IP клиента на VPS?

Tags: php, vps

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Выдает IP сервера. Как увидеть IP клиента?

PS на хостинге было просто)

Comment: убрать прокси, проверить заголовки X-Forwarded-For и  X-Real-IP

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($_SERVER);` и посмотрите в каком элементе у вас передается реальный ip.

Comment: У Вас видимо установлен NGINX. Почитайте статью http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html поможет настроить сервер правильно.

Comment: Да, сделал настройку по инструкции с интернета, nginx установлен)

Comment: VIsman - в очередной раз выручаете)

Comment: Добавил предположение, в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас видимо установлен NGINX. Почитайте [статью](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) поможет настроить сервер правильно.

Дело в заголовках, передаваемых при работе nginx в качестве реверс-прокси. Для приложения, работающего за nginx, любой клиент - локальный (с IP адресом сервера). Чтобы этого избежать, нужно исправлять заголовки, как указано в статье.